# Create array of hooks at runtime

Tags: reactjs

There's a thing that looks like this:

```
const [firstElem, setFirstElem] = useState();
const [secondElem, setSecondElem] = useState();
const [thirdElem, setThirdElem] = useState();

const elemArray = [firstElem, secondElem, thirdPhoto];
const setElemArray = [setFirstElem, setSecondElem, setThirdElem];
```

Its called like:

```
setElemArray[2](newValue);
```

Is there a way to create those hooks dynamically or use an alternative to support any amount of input elements, not just 3? Adding a hook for the whole array is totally ruining the performance.

Comment: No, it is not: fully unrolling code is one of the very last steps you typically do in order to squeeze out the very last bit of performance from code, and there is nothing in the code you're showing that's slow. So you might be investigating entirely the wrong thing if your goal is to improve performance. What made you think _this_ was your bottleneck?

Comment: You might want a single state to control all "controlled" inputs, or to use `useReducer`, either way, you must show us a producible example of what you expecting to happen.

Comment: Howdy. You got me a bit wrong, let me explain. I'm not chasing the performance, I just want to add support for like 1000 elements. It would be stupid to write stuff all the way up to "const [1000thElem, set1000thElem]=...", wouldn't it?

Comment: I expect to be able to call it like ``setElemArray[100](newValue);`` because changing that would make me change like 2000 lines of code all over the place.

Comment: @HMR each element has its own set function. I'm not passing anything.